# Heroku rebuild and redeploy with scheduler

Tags: heroku, deployment, automation, scheduler

I would like to have my app rebuilt and redeployed once per day. The reason for this is that I am using Jekyll and I display 'upcoming events'. I use LiquidScript to determine which events are 'upcoming', which ones are already in the past and which ones are too far in the future. But without redeploying, nothing on the site changes, even if I rebuild it. That's why I would like a solution to this, and one that can be made automatic with scheduler.